Charge induced on a plate by a point charge
Is there a way to derive the surface charge density induced on a circular conducting plate of radius $R$ due to a point charge $Q$ at a height $h$ above its center? If yes, please help me out.

@Vincent Thacker The method of images usually works for the case of an infinite conducting plate, or a conducting sphere. I haven't seen it for a finite radius circular plate.

There is an analytic expression for it (but it is not particularly simple...) See my added answer.

If the disk (of radius $R$) is somehow kept at potential $V=0$ (without introducing conductors that disturb the fields, of course) and the charge $Q$ is at height $h$ above its center, then a solution can be derived:
$$\begin{align}
 \sigma_0(r) &= \frac{ Q}{ \pi^2 r }\, \frac{d}{dr} \left(\!
\frac{ h}{ \sqrt{ r^2 + h^2}}\ \arctan \sqrt{\frac{{R^2 - r^2}}
{{r^2 + h^2}}}\ \right)
\\[5pt]
   &= \frac{-h\, Q}{ \pi^2 (h^2+r^2)^{3/2} }\, 
 \left( \sqrt{\frac{{ r^2 + h^2}}{ { R^2-r^2}}}+ 
\arctan \sqrt{\frac{{R^2 - r^2}}
{r^2 + h^2}}\ \right)   \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
From the first line, the total charge induced in the disk can then be found as:
$$
  Q_{\text{(ind)}} =\frac{-2 Q}{\pi}\ \arctan\big(\frac{R} {h}\big) 
$$
To get the case where the disk is floating, we first solve the case with the disk at potential $V$ in otherwise empty space. That case gives:
$$
  \sigma_V(r) = \frac{4\, \varepsilon_0 V}{\pi\,\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} \tag{2}
$$
with the total charge on the disk given by:
$$
  Q_V  = 8 \varepsilon_0 R\ V
$$
which, on a sidenote, shows that such a disk has capacitance $C=8 \varepsilon_0 R$, a bit less than a sphere of radius $R$ which has $C=4\pi \varepsilon_0 R$.
Finally, for the case of a floating disk with charge $Q$ above it we then have to
combine the solutions $\sigma_0(r)$ and $\sigma_V(r)$ in the ratio that gives total charge $0$. So we get
$$\begin{align}
  \sigma_{\text{(float)}}(r) &= \sigma_0(r)
  - \frac{Q_{\text{(ind)}}}{Q_V}\ \sigma_V(r) \\[5pt]
&= \sigma_0(r)
  + \frac{Q\,\arctan(R/h) }{\pi^2 R\,\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}
\end{align}$$
This expression (like the previous ones) is for the total charge density. To see the separate parts on the upper and lower surface, use the fact that they must be proportional to the normal $E$-field, which is made asymmetric by adding the field of the point charge $Q$, so:
$$\begin{align}
  \sigma_{\text{(float, top)}}(r) &= {\small \frac12}
 \sigma_{\text{(float)}}(r) 
-\frac{Q\,h}{4\pi (r^2+h^2)^{3/2}}
\\[5pt]
  \sigma_{\text{(float, bott.)}}(r) &= {\small \frac12} \sigma_{\text{(float)}}(r) 
+\frac{Q\,h}{4\pi (r^2+h^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}$$
(Note that $\sigma_{\text{(float)}}(r)$ is negative if $Q$ is positive, so most charge is on the top side.)
[EDITED] Proofs:

Eq. $(1)$ to my knowledge can most easily be obtained by using oblate spheroidal coordinates and then the limit for a flattened ellipsoid. Like many of these problems it might be hidden in William Smythe's "Static and Dynamic Electricity", but I don't immediately see it. (It is worth having a look for the 1930s flavor alone!) It is also found in: R. Rietman,"A Common-Mode Skeleton Model for EMC Simulations", in Scientific Computing in Electrical Engineering, Ursula van Rienen, Michael Günther, Dirk Hecht (Eds.), Lecture Notes in Computational Science and Engineering 18, Springer, 2001, pp 35-53.
Eq. $(2)$ was apparently derived by none other than Green. An excellent treatment is in Michael Fowler's Lecture notes, including a geometrical derivation without using any equations. But it also demonstrates the use of oblate spherical harmonics.

Plots
Here's a plot of $\sigma_0$ for $Q$=-$1, R$=$1, h$=$\frac13$, and below it $\sigma_{\text{(float, top)}}$ and $\sigma_{\text{(float, bott.)}}$ for the same values. Top charge is peaking in the center with sign opposite to the point charge $Q$, but changes sign near the edge, the bottom charge has the same sign as $Q$ everywhere. All edges of course show square-root singularities:




You probably didn't derive these equations on the back of an envelope yourself. They are definitely not common knowledge.  Could you give a source for these formulas and the method by which they were arrived at?

When I saw the question I was able, with some effort, to find them in decades old notes, and similar ones for electric dipoles above the disk, even de induced current by magnetic dipoles.
They look like something from the book of Smythe, and some were proved by Ronald Rietman (who did those things).
Double-checking the validity and more importantly the method of derivation are on my list. If I don't find out more, I'll might make a new question out of it!

BTW: Since this is tagged as "homework-and-exercises" it might be inappropriate to give the derivation...

Thanks for the reply, Jos. Got your point.

@Jos Bergervoet Thank you. My point is that the community usually, myself included,  want to learn something from the answers. Thus to  know by which method this solution was arrived at would be of benefit and help to tackle similar boundary value problems. E.g., if it was achieved by a special mirror charge assumption. In any case, this problem seems to be rather difficult and laborious for a run-of-the mill home work problem and  the complicated solution formulas don't give you any insight, except for the fact that they exist.

[EDITED ANSWER now has links to Smythe and Fowler added.] Absolutely, whoever added the "homework-and-exercises" tag probably did that jokingly :-) I'd actually love to see more results like this discussed on SE (I'm sure Smythe and Jackson would have liked that too!) As for the results, I think they were derived by just using the right coordinate system and finding the right ansatz. I added some links to the answer.

As this a rotationally symmetric problem, it could be considered effectively two-dimensional, so that you might be able to find a complex analytic function whose real or imaginary part are "harmonic functions" and thus solve the Laplace equation with the corresponding boundary condition for the potential.  Once you have that, you get the electric surface field on the plate an thus the surface charge. Otherwise, you can use a numerical procedure to find the solution of the Laplace equation, which might be tricky at the edges of the plate.
PS: As a response to some comments. You need the additional solution of only the Laplace equation to fulfill the potential boundary conditions when you start with the trivial point charge Coulomb potential solution, which formally can also be considered a solution of the Poisson equation with a delta charge inhomogeneity.

You mean Poissons equation due to the nonzero free charge present.

@Triatticus,  no, this is only a boundary condition problem for the Laplace equation because you have a metal with constant potential and resulting surface charge, but no distributed space charge. The surface charge follows from the gradient of the potential solution (normal E-field at the surface) of the Laplace equation.

@freecharly There is a point charge present.

@Vincent Thacker Thats right. Its potential solution is simply given by Coulombs law. Then you have to add the Laplace solution  so that the combination fulfills the potential boundary conditions. Of course, you could also consider this as the solution of the Poisson equation with a delta charge as inhomogeneity.
